# Mtaplotlib: TypeError: Object does not appear to be a 8-bit string path or a Python file-like object

Tags: python, matplotlib, mat

I have an array of image file names called 'img'. This variable looks like this:

```
['../realData/0.jpg', '../realData/1.jpg']
```

Want I want to do is iterate over this array and plot every picture with Matplotlib. This is my code:

```
for i in range(len(img)):
    img = mpimg.imread(img[i])
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
```

The first picture is displayed just fine but the second picture gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Maximal/Documents/Python/PyCharm/TrafficSignClassification/run/predictRealData.py", line 13, in <module>
    model.evaluateRealData(labelNames, imagePath)
  File "C:\Users\Maximal\Documents\Python\PyCharm\TrafficSignClassification\model\trafficSignsClassification.py", line 186, in evaluateRealData
    self.showImage(srcImg)
  File "C:\Users\Maximal\Documents\Python\PyCharm\TrafficSignClassification\model\trafficSignsClassification.py", line 225, in showImage
    img = mpimg.imread(img[i])
  File "C:\Users\Maximal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1436, in imread
    return handler(fname)
  File "C:\Users\Maximal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1390, in read_png
    return _png.read_png(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: Object does not appear to be a 8-bit string path or a Python file-like object

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What I don't understand is that the first picture is working and the second one is not. I used the windows snipping tool to capture both images and saved them as jpg file. In the explorer I can open both images just fine. How can this happen? These pictures should be identical regarding shape, size, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the variable `img`. I assigned the array I was iterating over the output frame from the first iteration.
So I had to change the code from this:

```
for i in range(len(img)):
    img = mpimg.imread(img[i])
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
```

to sth. like this:

```
for i in range(len(img)):
    image = mpimg.imread(img[i])
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

and it's working again.